# iOS Mobile SDK 3.0 - App Crashes

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

I recently downloaded the latest iOS Mobile SDK. I'm seeing a recurring crash when the app comes to foreground.

```
-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0 CoreFoundation + 130
1 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 38
2 CoreFoundation + 202
3 CoreFoundation + 706
4 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5 CoreFoundation + 44 
6 MyApp +[SFSecurityLockout inactivityExpired] + 100
7 MyApp +[SFSecurityLockout validateTimer] + 60 
8 MyApp -[SalesforceSDKManager handleAppForeground:] + 1060
```

Has anyone else seen this? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a known issue which has been reported by other users as well. I've reproduced it at my end also. The issue is being tracked on the Mobile SDK iOS Github repo [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/874).

It is also discussed on the [Mobile SDK Google+ community page.](https://plus.google.com/u/1/111580176477197776434/posts/FbXc7YxK3oD)